# Injecting elements and attaching Click event handlers in a loop with Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, event-handling, dom-events

I'm trying to make a dropdown which is populated from an array with Javascript. Each Item needs to have an event trigger attached, but it currently only attaches the event to the last element. I have tried the examples based on fixing closures but is still only attaches to the last element.

https://jsfiddle.net/z3h1uux4/

```
var ArrayUName = ["A","B","C"]
var ArraySlug = ["Q","W","E"]
for (i = 0; i < ArrayUName.length; i++) {
      var GoalID = ArrayUName[i] + '-' + ArraySlug[i];
      document.getElementById("TheContent").innerHTML +=
      '<a class="GoalIDBtn" id="' + GoalID + '">' + ArrayUName[i] + ' / ' + ArraySlug[i] + '</a></br>';
      (function(_i, _GoalID)
          {document.getElementById(_GoalID).addEventListener(
              "click",
               function() {alert("Click Made : " + _i)}
          );
      })(i, GoalID);
      console.log("Loop #" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `innerHTML` is a *destructive* property. It *recreates* the set content and creates *new* elements, the newly generated elements do no have any `click` handlers bound to them. You should create a node (element) instead of using `innerHTML`.

You can use the `document.createElement` and `HTMLElement.appendChild` methods instead:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.className = 'GoalIDBtn';
a.id = GoalID;
a.textContent = ArrayUName[i] + ' / ' + ArraySlug[i];
document.getElementById("TheContent").appendChild(a);
(function(_i /*, _GoalID*/) {
  a.addEventListener("click", function() {
      alert("Click Made : " + _i);
  });
})(i);
```

[Here is a demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxt11dLw/). Note that it  doesn't add the `br` elements and you can use the similar DOM APIs for creating them.

Comment: So if I had two do loops, one to create and one to add the handlers that would work?

Comment: @JasonAllan Yes, but that's not necessary. I'll update the answer to include a fiddle that 'works'.

Comment: Cancel That. Done it, Fix it. Thank you so much!